# Atribuir consulta ajax a uma variavel

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
             $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
 $.ajax({
  type:'post',  //Definimos o método HTTP usado
  dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
  url: 'getDados.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
  success: function(dados){
   for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
    //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
    


    $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].date+'</td><td>'+dados[i].result+'</td></tr>');
    
    
       }
      }
     });
    });


$('#tabela').append('['+dados[i].date+', '+dados[i].result+'], ');  // o retorno que preciso é nesta configuração
```

Estou criando uma consulta ajax e precisaria pegar o resultado e colocar numa variável, o código que eu encontrei coloca o resultado numa tabela, ja tentei de tudo que é jeito e não consigo colocar o retorno que preciso dentro de uma variável.

Preciso disto pois depois vou utilizar o resultado para criar um gráfico do google charts que atualize de tempo em tempo;

Comment: Lucas, só uma correção: **java != javascript**

Answer (score 0):

var array = [];

array = JSON.parse(dados);

com isso é para o retorno do ajax ir para um array